# C++ loop unfolding, bounds

Tags: c++, performance, loops

I have a loop that I want to unfold:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    do_stuff_for(i);
```

Unfolded:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i += CHUNK) {
    do_stuff_for(i + 0);
    do_stuff_for(i + 1);
    ...
    do_stuff_for(i + CHUNK-1);
}
```

But, I should make sure that I do not run out of the original N, like when N == 14 and CHUNK == 10. My question is: what is the best/fasters/standard/most elegant (you name it) way to do it?

One solution that comes is:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < (N % CHUNK); i++) 
    do_stuff_for(i);

for(i; i < N; i += CHUNK) {
    // unfolded, for the rest
}
```

But maybe there is a better practice

Comment: Why unroll? Does your compiler not support optimisations?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Visual C++ 10 will usually not attempt such aggressive optimizations.

Comment: a templated solution? that makes it easy to disable it for modern(*grin*) compilers..

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I noticed that when I do it myself, I get performance gain.

Comment: Are 'N' and 'CHUNK' known at compile time?

Comment: The "best way" to unroll is to let the compiler do it. It will know the optimum number of iterations inside and automatically generate the last non-even iterations as well. This screams micro-optimization that will cost you much more in maintenance than it pays  you.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a switch-case.

It's called **[Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)**

Comment: I am impressed with this D.D.!

Comment: @yi_H: indeed, fortunately it's a well-known little optimization trick, and normally obsolete now (though it might sometimes be needed in low-level routines).